# Cannot drop column in Cassandra 3.11

Tags: cassandra

Is it not possible to drop column on Cassandra 3.11?

We recently migrated from Cassandra 3.7 to 3.11, and while checking the compatibility we found that Alter Table table_name drop column_name does not work if the table has a materialized view (even though the column is not a part of any Materialized view).

This seems to be a bit odd as our DataModel has not changed even a single bit and it was possible on 3.7.

Certain other threads on SO suggested to drop materialized view first, then drop column and finally recreate your materialized views.

Even there seems to be no information regarding this in Cassandra Release notes for versions greater than 3.7.

Any idea if this is a bug on Cassandra?

Comment: Could be a bug, check Cassandra's JIRA: https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/CASSANDRA/issues & maybe file a bug...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's no longer possible to drop a column from a table with a materialized view.

This is in the 3.11.1 [release notes](https://git1-us-west.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cassandra.git;a=blob_plain;f=NEWS.txt;hb=refs/tags/cassandra-3.11.1): "Cassandra will no longer allow dropping columns on tables with Materialized Views."

If you want to see the [related code change, it is here](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/commit/e6fb8302848bc43888b0a742a9b0abce09872c45#diff-43b2d530031e2f7ad4286bd05fed4ca0L222).

Comment: That's a bummer... but it doesn't make sense to discourage dropping a column even though it is not part of the MV. Any suggestions on how to tackle this usecase, where dropping column is needed?

Answer (score 2):

Add the flag -Dcassandra.force_3_0_protocol_version=true to cassandra-env.sh. Upgrade cassandra on all nodes. Then, remove flag on all nodes and do rolling restart. By this way, drop will work.